# Small number of set categories with many-to-many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm relatively new to the Rails framework and I'm not sure if the approach I am taking is the most efficient/effective way or if I am following Rails conventions well.

The basic issue I have is that my application will have a Company model and various **set** Categories (not editable by the user). Each Company can be part of multiple Categories. My understanding, from other examples, is that I should set the relationships as something like:

- **Company** has_many_belongs_to_many **Categories**
- **Category** has_many_belongs_to_many **Companies**

However, since there will not be that many categories (<10), and since they will not change/be editable/be added/be removed by users, I'm not sure I need to create a whole new table for categories then join them onto Companies? Is there a better way to do this in Rails that I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you may only have 10 categories or so, I would say this is still fine to have it in its own table. Setting up the relationships give you programmatic power to retrieve companies related to a single category and vice versa when you need it without having to reconstruct queries yourself.

An example of the simplicity for keeping those in the database:

```
# Get all companies under a specific Category
@category = Category.find(1)
@companies = @category.companies
```

That's pretty simple if you ask me. And if you add another category to the table in the future, you won't need to write any new code to get it work.

Another thing, I would check out using `has_many :through` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` (habtm), as habtm can cause unforeseen problems as your application gets bigger. Here is a great article that goes into that problem a lot deeper: [Why You Don’t Need Has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/#sthash.9OEryqT0.dpuf). Not saying you can't use it (if the shoe fits), but generally it's good to be aware of potential problems so you can make the right decision for you and your app.